# How to access class variables in included ruby modules?

Tags: ruby, variables, module

I need to know if it is possible for included ruby modules to have access to class variables. Lets say:

```
require 'bar'

class Foo

 @i_am_important

  Bar.do_stuff

end

Module Bar
  def Bar.do_stuff
    @i_am_important.stuff...
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make the above working?

edit: improved example,
edit2: solved problem

I just changed my approach: Bar became a class of its own and gets "i_am_important" passed when initialized. Might not be the best solution, but works at last. Thanks for you help.

Comment: First of all, if you want to include module, you have to make all methods that would be available for hosted class as instance methods

Answer (score 0):

You can include module inside the class to get access like

```
    module MyModule
    @@my_val = 4
    end

    class MyClass
    include MyModule
    value = @@my_val
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but for my scenario I need @my_val in MyClass. Who could MyModule access it?

Comment: `@@my_val` isn't a global variable, it's a class instance variable

Comment: I just edited my example. I hope it is clearer now to see my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use variable across the gates of classes and module? I think there is such way:

```
module Bar
  def do_stuff
    puts im_am_important
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def im_am_important
    100
  end
end

Foo.new.do_stuff  # => 100
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#foo.rb

@var
module My_foo 
  var = @var
  def My_foo.my_method(var)
    puts(var)
  end
end
```

---

```
#bar.rb
require 'foo'

class Bar
  extend My_foo
  @important_var = "bla"
  My_foo.my_method(@important_var)
end
```

ruby bar.rb => bla

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that Foo already extends another class. That was kind of the reason why I tried to use modules after all.